# How to stop MATLAB from simplifying symbolic expressions?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

How to stop MATLAB from simplifying symbolic expressions?

I am working on a script for log-linearization of non-linear functions, and I need to rewrite such a function into this form:

```
x = z + w    ->    log(exp(log(x))) = log(exp(log(z)) + exp(log(w))
```

but MATLAB always automatically simplifies this function into:

```
log(x) = log(z + w)
```

I need to keep it in un-simplified form in order to do Taylor expansion and transform function into log-linear form.

Is there some option to switch-off simplifying for while in MATLAB?

Comment: Isn’t the simplified form easier to work with to do Taylor expansion? I don’t understand the problem!

Comment: Problem is that for log-linearization you need first to rewrite expression into this log(exp(log(z))) form, and after this, do Taylor expansion around log(zs) [zs = steady state of z]. So I realy need to keep it in this expanded form.